# What do I do when the Eclipse CDT indexer gets stuck?

Tags: workflow, eclipse-cdt, freeze, indexer

I'm using Eclipse CDT 2020-06 (but this has happened to me with earlier versions.)

Sometimes, the Eclipse CDT gets stuck parsing some file. The percentage indicator doesn't advance; and pressing the task's cancel button makes it "Cancel Requested", but it stays stuck that way. So, not only can I then not use the index for my project, but most other "async" tasks queue up and don't get carried out, either. When this happens I now basically give up and restart; and perhaps end up masking out the misbehaving file with a filter rule.

My question is: Is there something better I can do to handle the indexer getting stuck?

**edit:**

If I run Eclipse with -debug and enable indexer debugging, the only output I get is:

```
Indexer: start PDOMFastIndexerTask
Indexer: parsing /cuda-api-wrappers/examples/other/io_compute_overlap_with_streams.cu
```

and that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Probably Eclipse is running out of memory. Take a look at related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/9565125/72178.

Comment: @ks1322: Well, it's not actually a big project. And now the parser is stuck right at the beginning of starting to do anything, at 0%. Cancel

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to go to `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core` and delete the `*.pdom` files for my project.

Indexer was stuck at 0%, nothing else worked, including restarting eclipse, closing the project, refresh all, rebuild index, deleting the source files were it was stuck, etc.

Comment: Interesting... unfortunately, two years have passed, and I'm no longer experiencing this (plus I do more work in CLion right now).

Answer (score 2):

### How to "unstick" Eclipse's indexer

I've been using Eclipse professionally now on Linux (for code *editing* only, NOT building--which I do at the command-line) for 4 years, on *massive* mono-repos up to 200 GiB in code size. My indexer has gotten stuck hundreds of times, and these 2 solutions seem to pretty consistently work to "unstick" the indexer.

### 1. Increase the heap (RAM) available to Eclipse

Doubling my max RAM available to Eclipse from 8 GiB to 16 GiB fixed it for me. It was stuck for hours at `4841/7617 sources, 27463 headers`, parsing the same file forever, with the RAM maxed out at 8 GiB. Once I updated the RAM (heap) available to Eclipse from 8 to 16 GiB, I let the indexer run overnight for 10 hrs and by the morning it was finished.

Note: if trying to index the Boost libraries, some initial testing leads me to suspect it'll take Eclipse somewhere around a whopping **64 GiB~128 GiB of RAM (heap)** to index them, so I usually just exclude all or most of the Boost libraries from indexing as a general rule.

To double the RAM available to Eclipse, open (on Linux): `/home/username/eclipse/embedcpp-2021-06/eclipse/eclipse.ini`, or the equivalent path for you, and modify the `-Xmx` value. Ex: I increased mine from `-Xmx8196m` (8196 MiB, or 8 GiB) to `-Xmx16384m` (16384 MiB, or 16 GiB). Close and re-open Eclipse for this change to take effect.

Also, turn on showing the heap status at the bottom of the Eclipse window (if it isn’t already on by default):

**Window → Preferences → General → check the box for “Show heap status” → click “Apply and Close”**. Here’s what it looks like now at the bottom of the Eclipse window!

[image]

Source:

1. [My Google document above](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbuxOsDHfpMksGdpX5X-7l7o_TIIVFPkH2eD23cXUmA/edit?usp=sharing), p12.
2. See also: [How to view memory usage in eclipse (beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254187/how-to-view-memory-usage-in-eclipse-beginner/31255323#31255323)

#### You may need to give your PC more virtual memory to support the above RAM increase

If you don't have enough *physical RAM* to handle this increase, but you have a high-speed SSD, you can use your SSD as *virtual memory* to make up for not enough *physical memory*. This can be done on both Windows and Linux, and probably Mac too. If on Linux, [follow my instructions here to increase your vitual memory swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927854/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-swapfile-without-removing-it-in-the-terminal/1177620#1177620) to something more usable: ex: increase it to 32 GiB. Now, the max heap size you can set your Eclipse to use will be equal to *physical memory (real RAM)* + *virtual memory swapfile (fake "RAM" emulated on your solid state drive)*. Leave a few GiB for other programs though--don't give it *all* to Eclipse.

### 2. Exclude all build folders and 3rd-party libraries (especially Boost!) which you do not need to index

See my very-detailed answer on how to do this using 1) Resource Filters, and 2) a manual symlink-generator script (my preferred choice) here: [How to exclude all parts of a folder in Eclipse except for a few specific sub-folders within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267494/how-to-exclude-all-parts-of-a-folder-in-eclipse-except-for-a-few-specific-sub-fo/70267495#70267495)

### Going further

I write about this and a ton of other settings and things you might find useful in my Eclipse setup document you can find here:

1. https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse.
2. [Direct link to the Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbuxOsDHfpMksGdpX5X-7l7o_TIIVFPkH2eD23cXUmA/edit?usp=sharing)

See also: [What's the recommended Eclipse CDT configuration for big C++ project (indexer takes forever)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565125/whats-the-recommended-eclipse-cdt-configuration-for-big-c-project-indexer-ta/9633822#9633822)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something better I can do to handle the indexer getting stuck?

You can try to debug Eclipse indexer yourself. Run Eclipse from console with `-debug` option:

```
eclipse -debug <options file>'
```

where <options file> contents is:

```
org.eclipse.cdt.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.cdt.core/debug/indexer/activity=true
org.eclipse.cdt.core/debug/indexer/statistics=true
org.eclipse.cdt.core/debug/indexer/problems=true
```

Look at debug output when indexer is stuck. You will probably see some error messages from indexer which can be googled further.

Comment: So, I did that. There is no error message - it's just stuck on some file. And the file itself isn't even particularly noteworthy. The last console output line is: `Indexer: parsing /cuda-api-wrappers/examples/modified_cuda_samples/matrixMulDrv/matrixMul.cu`

Answer (score 1):

I have reason to believe this may have something to do with NVIDIA's Eclipse plugins for CUDA support. The indexer gets stuck on `.cu` files; and with a new version of Eclipse and without the plugins, indexing concludes without a hitch.

Comment: Still could potentially be a RAM issue (maybe?) if those are text files and it thinks it can index them. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69924563/4561887). What is inside of .cu files and how big are they?